DC voltage increases when going through a Diode
I am charging two 18650 batteries using a 600ma 5v solar panel.  I control the charging by monitoring the battery strength via an Arduino Pro Mini and turning ON/OFF an HFD2/005-M-L2 relay.  The positive feed from the solar cell is connected to the Anode side of a 1N4007 diode and then from the Cathode side goes to the relay and then on to the positive side of the batteries.  The negative feed of the solar cell is connected to the negative side of the batteries.  When testing the mA of the solar cell with a voltmeter I get a reading of .540mA when the positive probe is applied before the diode.  However when I apply the probe on the cathode side of the diode and beyond I get a reading of 7.XXXmA.  Why is this happening and is this truly the amount of current entering the battery?  Is this bad for the batteries?  Above I have included an image of the basic set up.

Do you think you are measuring current? One basic tenet is the current is the same at all points in a simple circuit.

Are you measuring voltage (as in the title) or current (as in the question)?  How are you measuring it - i.e how are you connecting the meter?

the voltmeter has a place to plug in the positive probe into labeled 5ADC and I set it to 5A.  When I place the + probe onto the positive out of the solar cell it reads .54 but when I put the probe on the cathode side of the diode and the - side of the battery I get a 7.XXX reading.  Since the voltmeter is only rated at 5A the voltmeter stops reading for a while until it resets.  So I am reading AmpsDC.

To measure current you have to break the circuit and reconnect so the entire current flows through the ammeter - i.e. out of the solar cell into the ammeter, out of the ammeter into the diode.

could I come out of the diode into the ammeter, out of the ammeter into the battery?  Or does the ammeter be before the diode always.

You can put it anywhere you want in the circuit, but you have to connect it so all the current flows through the meter.

OK thank you very much.  Got it.

You have your meter set on amps, right? When you put your +ve probe on the solar panel you are reading the current output of the solar panel. When you put your +ve probe on the cathode side of the diode you are measuring the short circuit current of the batteries! The batteries are simply discharging through your ammeter.
